# How to style scrollbars with JSS?

Tags: jss

How can I style the scrollbars with [JSS](http://cssinjs.org/?v=v9.8.7)? The solution below does not work.

```
   '::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
     background: 'red',
   },
   '::-webkit-scrollbar': {
     width: 10,
     background: 'red',
   },
   '::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
     background: 'green',
   },
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In JSS, pseudo-elements are prefixed with an ampersand. Give the following a try:

```
'&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
    background: '#888'
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to hide it instead of styling it: `'&::-webkit-scrollbar': { width: 0, height: 0 }` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49278385/1385429